# Bluetooth connects after many tries

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04, settings

I'm on ubuntu 20.04 and whenever I try to connect to my bluetooth device, it takes about 5-10 tries to connect to it. Here's a link to the video demonstrating the same thing, https://i.imgur.com/BCirvcd.mp4

It would be really helpful if someone can help me avoid that!

Comment: Having a similar problem. Currently trying the recommendations in this section of this page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_mouse#Thinkpad_Bluetooth_Laser_Mouse_problems

Comment: any solutions @WaylonFlinn?

Comment: Not really. There is a workaround though, I installed bluetooth quick connect extension, which connects bluetooth automatically or else I can easily choose from the menu.